# opensuse leap 15.4, installing apps from .ymp files (one click install) with the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, opensuse

I have a new (to me) opensuse leap 15.4 installation with the generic desktop (just ICEWM, no file manager) for I use mc as my file manager.
Several apps I need I could only find as .ymp files, "One click to Install" files.
Except in mc they don't, not with one click, two clicks nor just pressing Enter.

https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:One_Click_Install_UserFAQ maintains that .ymp files can be installed at the command line by

> From openSUSE 11.0 you can. Simply run /sbin/OCICLI One Click Install Link

Unfortunately my /sbin shows no such animal, so I tried to get this from same url

> If you want to have the command line support on openSUSE 10.3 you can install the updated one click install handler.

which delivers another .ymp file, ymp.ymp, as if to rub it in.

What am I missing about handling these .ymp files?

Comment: What apps are you actually missing? The chances are they are available. Try running `yast2` or `yast2 sw_single` and have it search for the required software. Anyway, try `/usr/bin/OneClickInstallCLI` or `/usr/bin/OneClickInstallUI`, and if they are not installed, then do it with `zypper in yast2-metapackage-handler`.

Comment: I have installed them already, manually. Just wanted to know what I'm missing with ymps, as they seem less effort.  And thank you @Bib, I do have OneClickInstall in /usr/bin as you suggest, not in /sbin as my previous reference advised, so I think you have solved this little problem, but I can't see how to credit you with the solution.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Check, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What apps are you actually missing? The chances are they are available. Try running yast2 or yast2 sw_single and have it search for the required software. Anyway, try /usr/bin/OneClickInstallCLI or /usr/bin/OneClickInstallUI, and if they are not installed, then do it with zypper in yast2-metapackage-handler. If you need software installed, you really should be using the `yast2` tools.